# create multiple symlink of dirs linux

Tags: linux, symlink

I have a *.csv file with one column with a lot of rows that get a path:

```
name
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 15_09_00.622221_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 15_39_05.356679_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 17_09_19.458480_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 17_39_24.224640_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 19_09_38.520116_frames
2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 19_39_43.210493_frames
```

I would to create a symlink of each dir path in *.csv to `/data/test`

Thanks

Comment: `ln -s`, sometimes life is easy :-)

Comment: How can I do this by reading a *.csv?

Comment: `sed`, `awk`, plenty of examples all over the internet.

Comment: what is 'name' in your file? what is the root directory of 2020/11-2020/Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 19_39_43.210493_frames ?